# Second img doesn't show preview

Tags: javascript

There are ***two*** input file type and each has a corresponding image to display. Displaying Picture 1 definitely works but when its time to add another picture in Picture 2, it doesn't display any. Does the ***javascript*** code attached only support 1 input file type?

**HTML**

```
<label class="display-4">Picture 1</label>
<input type='file' name="row11" required/>
</center>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <center>
<img name="row11" src="#" alt="" height=1000 width=1000>
</center>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <center>
<label class="display-4">Picture 2</label>
<input type='file' name="row12" required/>
</center>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <center>
<img name="row12" src="#" alt="" height=1000 width=1000>
</center>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var img = document.querySelector('img'); // $('img')[0]
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url
      img.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `querySelector` selects only a single element. You need `querySelectorAll` and a loop to attach the listeners to all the inputs.

Comment: Also don't use `<center>` tag, it is deprecated. Use CSS instead. text-align: center on yoiur form-group.

Comment: @Teemu, No wonder aight.

Comment: @cloned, Noted will do some revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')** will return first element in the page. Use **querySelectorAll** to get all input file field. Also you need to get adjacent image tag to display the selected image. You are using same name for input file tag as well as img tag. So based on your code I am fetching img tag from the selected input file name attribute.

Below is the working example.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Class</title>
   
    <script>

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var fileInputs =  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
            if (fileInputs && fileInputs.length > 0) {
                fileInputs.forEach(function(inputFileField) {
                    inputFileField.addEventListener('change', function () {
                    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                        var fileInputName = this.getAttribute('name');
                        var img = document.querySelector('img[name="'+fileInputName+'"]'); // $('img')[0]
                        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url
                        img.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    }
                });
            });
           
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <label class="display-4">Picture 1</label>
    <input type='file' name="row11" required />
    </center>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <center>
            <img name="row11" src="#" alt="" height=1000 width=1000>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <center>
            <label class="display-4">Picture 2</label>
            <input type='file' name="row12" required />
        </center>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <center>
            <img name="row12" src="#" alt="" height=1000 width=1000>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Noted. Thank you prathameshk73!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over *all* `input[type="file"]`s, add a listener to each, and dynamically select the associated `img` tag:

```
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')) {
  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      const img = input.closest('.form-group').nextElementSibling.querySelector('img');
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url
      img.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    }
  });
}
```